# Re use the list table for a custom post type on another page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-list-table

i've got a custom post type which is 'ai1ec_event'. So i have a "All events" page which has a Wp_List_Table with all my events and my customization to that table.

Is there a way to draw the same list table on a different page, without extending Wp_List_table but just reusing something?